# How can I get result set from Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, resultset

I have a table below:

```
CREATE TABLE jun_t AS
SELECT 1 seq, -2000 amt FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 4000 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 3, -5000 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 4, -2000 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 3000 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 6, 1500 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 7, -250 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 8, 320 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 9, -4000 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 10, 10000 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 11, -20000 FROM dual;
```

And I had something to do,so I created and executed a pl/sql program below:

```
DECLARE

    CURSOR csr is
    select seq, amt
    from jun_t;

    rec csr%ROWTYPE;
    total jun_t.amt%TYPE;

BEGIN

    OPEN csr;

    total := 0;
    LOOP
        FETCH csr into rec;
        EXIT WHEN csr%NOTFOUND;

        IF (rec.amt + total) > 0 THEN
            total := rec.amt + total;
        ELSE
            total := 0;
        END IF;

        dbms_output.put_line(rec.seq || ',' || rec.amt || ',' || total);

    END LOOP;

END;
```

And the result is this:

```
1,-2000,0
2,4000,4000
3,-5000,0
4,-2000,0
5,3000,3000
6,1500,4500
7,-250,4250
8,320,4570
9,-4000,570
10,10000,10570
11,-20000,0
```

The problem is this. I want to use this result set in my c# application, but I can't find a way... I saw a sample code which use ref cursor, but it seems doesn't work in this case.

I want to make a stored procedure with this code.

Please somebody teach me a way to solve it, Or tell me What I should study.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you planning to use anonymous blocks or invoke a stored procedure?

Comment: I am planning to use a stored procedure. sorry, myquestion is lack of detail.

Comment: In that case, be aware that Oracle enables you to have tables as arguments of stored procedures (much like any other type), and you can define the argument is INOUT. As such, you create an empty table in the invoking program, pass it to the stored procedure, and have it back into your (invoking) code with all the values there.

Answer (score 0):

You can converted it into a stored procedure that returns a cursor. But it's far easier to get rid of PL/SQL and use a simple SQL query:

```
SELECT seq, amt
FROM jun_t;
```

Then compute the total in C#. If need, perform the conversion to a single comma separated line in C# as well. It's far easier than managing code in two places and using ref cursors.

BTW: The OPEN cursor / LOOP / FETCH INTO / EXIT WHEN pattern is completely outdated.

Comment: thanks. would you tell me the reason of 'BTW'? I am a novice to oracle, so I am curious of it.

Comment: It's much shorter and easier to write `FOR rec IN (SELECT seq, amt FROM jun_t) LOOP ...do..something..with..rec... END LOOP;`. And you can't forget to close the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You could get your desired output from a single sql query and pass the output ref cursor. `FETCH` this `CURSOR` in your c# code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_get_total ( p_csr OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
AS
BEGIN

OPEN p_csr FOR
WITH cte(seq, amt, total) 
     AS (SELECT 0 seq, 
                0 amt, 
                0 total 
         FROM   dual 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT j.seq AS  seq, 
                j.amt, 
                CASE 
                  WHEN j.amt + total < 0 THEN 0 
                  ELSE j.amt + total 
                END   AS total 
         FROM   jun_t j 
                join cte c 
                  ON j.seq = c.seq + 1) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte WHERE seq > 0;

END;
/
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6aac/1)

**Note**: This could be faster than computing  sum record by record after fetching from a simple cursor `select * from yourtable`,esp for large datasets.

Comment: Thank you very much. You looks like a guru of oracle.no, you are a oracle. but it seems that do not work in oracle 10g. Is there a way to solve this problem in oracle version 10g?